# Reading User Input in Linux

Tags: macos, shell

I have written a script for listing files based on the month which is read by the user as below:-

```
echo "Enter Month"
read month
ls -al | awk '$6 == "$month" {print}'
```

And i am giving the user input as Aug, i am not getting any result. But when i am writing

```
ls -al | awk '$6 == "Aug" {print}'
```

I am getting the exact result. Am i doing something wrong? Please help

Comment: MacOS (tag) is not Linux (title).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main thing is: variable names are not expanded inside single quotes. This is a "better" (i.e. a little less wrong) line:

```
ls -al              | awk '$6 == "'"$month"'" {print}'
# this is in single quotes ^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^
```

But:

0. Still this may fail in some locales. [Set `LC_ALL=C` beforehand](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/108618) or so maybe.
1. With `$month` you can inject (almost?) anything into `awk`. There are better ways to use variables within `awk`; [`-v` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19075707) should be a lot safer (thank you user000001 for pointing this out).
2. [You shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in the first place.

The right solution might use `find` and `stat`. The following code may not be the fastest solution but it's more robust due to:

- discarding `$month` values that don't match predefined ones,
- using `find` instead of parsing `ls`.

The code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter Month"
read month
case "$month" in
  1|01|Jan|jan|January|january)   monthN=01;;
  2|02|Feb|feb|February|february) monthN=02;;
# ...
  10|Oct|oct|October|october)     monthN=10;;
# ...
  *) echo Error! >&2; exit 1;;
esac
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -exec sh -c '[ `stat -c %y "$1" | cut -c 6-7` = "$2" ]' sh {} "$monthN" \; -ls
```

I tested this on Debian; it may not be super-portable. It shows the general approach though.

The last line invokes a separate shell for every object in the current directory (including `./` itself). This shell uses `stat` to get mtime information, then `cut` extracts two-digit month number from it. `[ ... ]` compares the result to the chosen month number. If this test succeeds then `find` performs its own `ls` on the object (you may use `-print` or `-print0` instead).

Note this never returns `../`. On the other hand `find` allows you to use additional tests (like `-type f`), so this approach is very flexible.

Comment: Add another item in the brokenness list: You use string interpolation for passing variables to awk, instead of using the `-v` option, which is much safer.